# Changing webpack generated image src with javascript after twig has rendered template

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, twig

What is the right aproach, to change an webpack generated image source with javascript?

I'm using Webpack with Symfony 4.
I'm used to change colors of font awesome icons and stuff with javascript, which is no problem at all. But now it comes to using asset images.

In my Twig template i have something like:

```html
<img class="" id="gig-gema-icon" src="{{ asset ('public/build/images/gema_grey.png') }}" alt="gema-icon">
```

Now I want to change the image source. Obviously it's pointless to do something like

```js
$('#gig-gema-icon').attr("src", "{{ asset ('public/build/images/gema_grey.png') }}");
```

in javascript.

Even if I knew the filename webpack created, I wouldn't use it in javascript for obvious reasons.

How do I deal with this problem.
because twig has to generate an url when the template is rendered.
The generated filename looks like

```html
<img id="gig-gema-icon" class="" src="/labelDB/build/images/gema_grey.7dd801c7.png" alt="gema-icon">
```

Thank you so much for your help.

p.s. Any suggestions for a better subject for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to rely on `data` attributes, e.g.

```
<img data-source="{{ asset ('public/build/images/gema_grey.png') }}" />
```

You could then access this attribute in your javascript whenever,

```
$('img[data-source]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('source'));
});
```

Comment: This is just perfect! Thank you so much.